# Accurate changes in execution time

Tags: c, linux

I'm looking for a way to very accurately measure the execution time of a program. As part of an exercise I'm trying to perform a side-channel attack on a file that compares my command line argument against a password of length 19. For each character that is wrong, the execution enters a nested loop.

I'm considering writing an execution wrapper where my program would fork, the parent would execve the exercise binary, the child would wait for the parent and time the execution from the fork onward to the wait(&status); call.

Would this be a good approach? What would be other options I could explore? What would be my best bet in trying to time the execution with a good level of precision?

Comment: Measure CPU time or wall time?

Comment: Have you considered the system call `gettimeofday()`?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have very specific requirements, you can just use `/bin/time` or `time` (shell buildin with similar functionality).

Comment: Does `time` use `gettimeofday()`? Also, what happens when `time` is swapped when you have a weak cpu?

Comment: @lrobb I don't think so, it would use system calls such as `times(2)` or `getrusage(2)`, but I didn't checked the details. You can check [sources of GNU version of time](ftp://prep.ai.mit.edu/pub/gnu/time/) if you are interested.